# is this listz or beethoven?

Tags: classical-music, soundtrack

Found this but cant name it

http://sndup.net/kbqz

apps couldn't either

Comment: That sounds modern to my ear, but I certainly doubt it's from Beethoven's era.

Comment: It sounds like a bad pastiche, imitating probably rather Chopin than Liszt, or maybe film music informed (but not enough) by the same.

Comment: Of course the second half sounds rather like Orff than anything from the nineteenth century